# Regex to find attributes which has null values

Tags: java, regex, rest-assured

I'm using REST Assured framework for the API testing and am facing some difficulties in finding attributes having null values. I really dont have any idea about regex :P

So, the API response is like

```
"data": [
        {
            "type": "social",
            "id": "164",
            "attributes": {
                "created_time": "2014-09-12",
                "currency": "INR",
                "budget": 381000,
                "end_time": null,
                "name": "Untitled",
                "start_time": "2022-09-12",
                "updated_time": "2014-09-12"
            }
```

I need to find attributes which is having null values like `"end_time"`.
If there is any other way to find such attributes, It will be really helful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: some json parsing dependency would do it somehow depends which one you are using  , instead of going through string once with regex and then parsing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for `null` attributes in JSON text, you can use following regex:

```
/"([^"]+)": null/
```

Above regular expression will capture in group 1 all the attributes with value `null`.

Explanation:

- **"** - match quote
- **(** - begin of capture group
- **[^"]+** - will match (capture) one or more characters which are not quote
- **)** - end of capture group
- **"** - match quote
- **: null** - literally match colon, followed by space, followed by `null`

Above explanation translated to plain English: Capture all characters which are between quotes, followed by colon, space and `null`.

Depending on the language you use to execute the regular expression, you need to specify the global flag to match all the attributes. The first matching group usually is the first element of the result and is array.

Depending on your language, the forward slashes '/' might be required or not - regex could be specified as string or the language could support regex notation - with slashes. In the latest,usually the global flag is specified by adding `g` after the closing slash.

In Java

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// Retrieve response from the REST API    
String json_response = receiveResponse();

// Define the regex pattern
String pattern = "\"([^\"]+)" *: *null";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(json_response);
if (m.find( )) {
   // Print the entire match
   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );   // > "end_time": null
   // Print capture group 1
   System.out.println("Found null for: " + m.group(1) ); // > end_time
} else {
  System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

You can iterate over all matching fields:

```java
while (m.find( )) {
   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
   System.out.println("Found null for: " + m.group(1) );
}
```

Comment: yeah.. thanks.. but when I'm extracting response as a string and then using regex to find attributes, its not searching.

Comment: String token = res.getBody().asString();
System.out.println(token.matches("\"([^\"]+)\": null"));

Comment: Ah, you are using Java. The matches() method tries to match the entire string to the regular expression. We need to match only a part of the string. Added Java example.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Really appreciate your help.!